# Packing an sqlite DB only on first installation

Tags: android, sqlite, google-play-services

I have an app that uses a sqlite db of size 30 mb (in zipped the size is 13 mb).
The updates are costly in size since the sqlite db is getting downloaded every time even though there is no change in data.

I have the following solutions in mind.

**Approach 1:**
Download the db on the launch of the app (if the db is not already present). So, the updates will not download. Problem with this approach is user needs to wait till the download is complete. It might make the user to uninstall the app since he has to wait.

**Approach 2:**
Put the sqlite db in the expansion file and it will downloaded in the play store before installation itself.

I am planning to take the approach 2.
Is it fine? In the approach 2,

> 1. Will the android allows to put an expansion file even though my app
>    size is less than 50 mb?
> 2. Will android show warning like "This app is going to do huge download.
>    Use it only on Wi-Fi kind of warning?

Answer (score 0):

You can add the zipped DB file in your assests folder and first time when your app is launched unzip and copy the DB file from assests folder to the application memory.Now you can use it easily.

**Note**-One drawback of this approach is that you won't be able to delete the DB file from assests folder because it is readable only.

Comment: On every update, this DB should be given irrespective of whether I change this DB or not right? Updates are unnecessarily costly for the user right?